# Pymongo $in Query Not Working

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

Seeing some strange behavior in Pymongo `$in` query.  Looking for records that meet the following query:

```
speciesCollection.find({"SPCOMNAME":{"$in":['paddlefish','lake sturgeon']}})
```

The query returns no records.

If I change it to find_one the it works returning the last value for Lake Sturgeon.  The field is a text filed with one vaule. So I am looking for records that match paddlefish or Lake Sturgeon.

It works fine in Mongo Shell like this:

```
speciesCollection.find({SPCOMNAME:{$in: ['paddlefish','lake strugeon']}},{_id:0})
```

Here is the result from shell

```
{ "SPECIES_ID" : 1, "SPECIES_AB" : "LKS", "SPCOMNAME" : "lake sturgeon", "SP_SCINAME" : "Acipenser fulvescens
{ "SPECIES_ID" : 101, "SPECIES_AB" : "PAH", "SPCOMNAME" : "paddlefish", "SP_SCINAME" : "Polyodon spathula" }
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you have a typo or some other error in your program as I just did a test with your sample data and query and it works - see the GIF

Below is my test code which connects to the database called `so` and the collection `speciesCollection`, maybe you find the error in yours with it

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('dockerhostlinux1', 30000)
db = client.so
coll = db.speciesCollection

result = coll.find({"SPCOMNAME":{"$in":['paddlefish','lake sturgeon']}})
for doc in result:
    print(doc)
```

[image: GIF]

Comment: Epic fail on my part. Arrggh!!